# jQuery Wont Work For Safari or Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, safari

I wrote the below code:

```
jQuery('.infoBox').hide();

jQuery('.read').click(function() {
    jQuery('.infoBox').hide();
    jQuery('.panel-row-style-for-'+ jQuery(this).attr('title')).show();
    jQuery('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: (jQuery('#pg-11-1').first().offset().top -100)
    },500);
});
```

It hides multiple infoBox elements when the page loads, then when user clicks at the top to certain links, it opens one of the hidden at a time.

First of all, if I change jQuery tag in front of every line to $ it gives an error saying

> $ is not a function.

Secondly, it works fine on Chrome, IE, Edge, Firefox but not Safari or Mobile.

Comment: How are you including jquery?

Comment: It's wordpress, it comes included.

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? Safari is only officially supported in 1.12 and lower.

Comment: Is this code in a `document.ready` function or on the page?

Comment: No, it's in the head section wrapped with script code. <script type="text/javascript">  and </script>

Comment: The code might be loading before the DOM is ready. Try wrapping it in an document.ready function.

Comment: Rory, It has this for jQuery, so I assume 1.12.4? `<script type="text/rocketscript" data-rocketsrc="http://marlysbeider.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4"></script>`

Comment: That was the catch, SamBremner. Thank you!

Comment: Any idea why it says $ is not a function? I usually use $ to represent jQuery when I code and never had a problem..?